# Getting data from a complex query to excel

Tags: sql-server-2000, excel-2003

I've got a query which I want to depend on certain parameters from an excel sheet, but I get the error 'parameters are not allowed in queries that can't be displayed graphically'. The only way to get around it that I see is to use a view, but how much extra overhead would that give? It would mean joining two tables (one with near 70000 and one with over 200000 records and both having around 40 fields) into that view, probably using only 5 or so of the total 80 fields. We do not have a test server. Alternatively, is there a way to change the following query to one for which microsoft query does allow parameters?

```
select count(distinct a) from table1 where b=0 and c < '2010-01-01' and a in 
(select a from table2 where d between '2010-01-01' and '2010-12-31')
```

or as a join:

```
select count(distinct table1.a) from table1 inner join table2 on (table1.a=table2.a 
and table2.d between '2010-01-01' and '2010-12-31') where table1.c < '2010-01-01'
and table1.b=0
```

I want to replace the dates (for c and d) with cellvalues.

Thanks,

Ernst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considering migrate the data from Excel to SQL-Server tables and then execute the query?. The most of the DBMS have tools for data migration.

Comment: I hadn't thought about that, I don't think it's an option though. Other people will have to add things too. Although if it sql can do the import automatically from an excel sheet every hour or on saving, it might be an option. I think I'll try the view option first after normal work hours.

Comment: @Ernst: You should create a Macro to automatically export data from Excel to SQL server, so you can execute complex queries. SQL excel is limited.